# If $a_0+a_1+...+a_n\neq 0$ and $a_0x+a_1f(x)+a_2f^2(x)+...+a_nf^n(x)=0 \forall x \in [a, b],$ prove that $a\cdot b<0$

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

> Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$ and $f:[a,b]\to [a,b]$ be a continuous function. If $a_0, a_1, ..., a_n\in \mathbb{R}$ and $a_0+a_1+a_2+...+a_n\neq 0$ and $a_0x+a_1f(x)+a_2f^2(x)+...+a_nf^n(x)=0, \forall x \in [a,b]$, prove that $a\cdot b<0$
> (Note: By $f^n(x), f\cdot f\cdot ...\cdot f \hspace{.3cm}(n \text{ times})$ is meant.)

Honestly, I am at a loss. My first idea was to say that $a_0a+a_1f(a)+a_2f^2(a)+...+a_nf^n(a)=0$ and that $a_0b+a_1f(b)+a_2f^2(b)+...+a_nf^n(b)=0$  and manipulate both of these some way, but really I am getting nowhere. This problem was taken from an old high school textbook but the author provides no solution.

Comment: Is this for arbitrary $a_0,\ldots,a_n$ and arbitrary $f$? Or, is it asking to prove that there are $a_0,\ldots,a_n$, $f\in C([a,b])$, that satisfy $a_0+\cdots+a_n\neq 0$ and $a_0x + a_1f(x)+\cdots + a_nf^n(x) = 0, \forall x\in[a,b]$, so that $ab < 0$?

Comment: Mind to include the author, name of the book

Comment: I think you are missing something. Let $n=1$, $a_0=a_1=1$, so $a_0+a_1=2$. Then let $f(x)=-x$, defined on the interval $[a,b]=[1,2]$. Then $a_0x+a_1f(x)=x-x=0$. But $ab=2>0$.

Comment: It is supposed to be for an arbitrary $f$. The book is one of Greek Origin, dating back to 1995, so I don't think it will be of much use. Anyway, it is not on the Internet and they don't sell copies anymore.

Comment: @Andrei $f(x)=-x$ doesn't take $[1,2]$ into itself so your counterexample is not valid

Comment: Are you sure that $f^n$ denotes the *multiplication* of $f$ by itself $n$ times ? It seems more logical to mean the *composition*.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe The problem specifically states that it means multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is not true.

Consider $f : [1,4] \rightarrow [1,4]$ defined for all $x \in [1,4]$ by
$$f(x)=2 \sqrt{x}$$

(so $a=1$ and $b=4$).

Let $a_0 = - 4$, $a_1 = 0$ and $a_2 = 1$. Then one has
$$a_0 + a_1 + a_2 \neq 0$$

and for all $x \in [0,1]$,
$$a_0 x + a_1 f(x) + a_2 f^2(x) = - 4x + 4x =0$$

but $ab > 0$.

Comment: there is an even simpler example $x-2x/2=0$ so $x/2$ works on $[0,1]$ but I think that $ab \le 0$ is true so either $ab<0$ or one of them is zero

Comment: @Conrad Let's wait for the OP to clarify the statement, then.

Comment: The problem explicitly states that $a \cdot b <0$ must hold, but obviously, there are counterexamples to that statement. I am not sure whether it can be proven that $ab\leq 0$. Honestly, it seems obvious that one of them could be $0$, but not at all obvious what happens if neither of them are.

Comment: @Conrad I edited. The conclusion $ab \leq 0$ is not true either.

Comment: @McBucketNuggets I edited.

Comment: correct! note that if the statement had composition instead of multiplication, $ab \le 0$ would be easily shown to be correct

Comment: @Conrad how so?

Comment: see answer below

Answer (score 0):

If in the OP the hypothesis involves composition ie $f^n=f^{\circ n}$ then it follows that $ab \le 0$

Since $f$ continuous preserves $[a,b]$ there is a fixed point $w \in [a,b]$

(as $f(a)-a \ge 0, f(b)-b \le 0$, the image of $[a,b]$ under $f(x)-x$ is a closed interval that contains zero possibly as an end point)

But then the given equation implies $(a_0+...a_n)w=0$ hence by hypothesis $w=0$ hence $0 \in [a,b]$ so $ab \le 0$

Now the example $f:[0,1] \to [0,1], f(x)=x/2, a_0=1, a_1=-2$ shows that unless some other conditions are imposed, we can have $a=0$ so $ab=0$ and not $ab<0$